# How to resolve a Fresh Vcenter appliance reporting "Unable to save IP settings"

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

A known issue in [Vcenter 7.0 Release notes](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/rn/vsphere-vcenter-server-701-release-notes.html) occurs when:

> In the Server Appliance, you configure a static IP or try to change the IP configuration.

> The following error results:
> `Unable to save IP settings.`
> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is a DNS problem.

While VMware currently reports `Workaround: None` - you can solve it by updating `/etc/hosts`

Solution:

- ssh as `root` into the vcenter appliance.
- elevate with the `shell` command.
- edit the hosts file: `vi /etc/hosts`
- Add the following line, leaving any existing entries. (Where vcenter.mydomain.local matches the `FQDN` you assigned during setup)
  `127.0.0.1 vcenter.mydomain.local vcenter localhost`
- To save and exit `vi` type `:wq!` and hit return.

The final file should look something like this:

```
# End /etc/hosts (network card version)  
# VAMI_EDIT_BEGIN  
# Generated by Studio VAMI service. Do not modify manually.  
127.0.0.1 vcenter.mydomain.local vcenter localhost  
::1 vcenter.mydomain.local vcenter localhost ipv6-localhost ipv6-loopback  
# VAMI_EDIT_END
```

You must also update `/etc/systemd/network/10-eth0.network` to include

```
DHCP=yes
```

(You can set it back to `no` after advancing the wizard - [no restarts required](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/vSphere-Upgrade-Install/After-fresh-install-of-a-VCSA-7-0-U1-FQDN-Problems-during/td-p/2293998))

Comment: Strange because I had fully working forward and reverse DNS in my domain, but this fixed the issue for me. Thank you!